# system logging other than journalctl

Tags: logs

I've been assuming that `journalctl` is comprehensive aggregator of system logs but I find out this is incorrect.

For example `dmesg` provides logging of system before systemd is fully activated and presents a more precise view of hardware states and process.

Are there other standard or useful system logging facilities that knowledgeable sysadmins use in linux?

Comment: Journalctl includes all the information presented in `dmesg` (that's what you get when you ask `journactl` for kernel logs, e.g., `journalctl -k`).

Comment: Journalctl will not include information for applications that log directly to files, but it will have everything sent to stdout/stderr by things run under `systemd`, and everything logged via the legacy `/dev/log` syslog api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been assuming that journalctl is comprehensive aggregator of system logs but I find out this is incorrect.

It kind of is!  Journalctl is part of systemd systems; on these, all things concerning the life time of services, logins etc are indeed logged to the journal: Basically, everything that systemd does or knows of. This also involves services that are started through a systemd service file, which (as default) logs the standard output of these services to the journal.

However, every program is free to log however it wants. For example, your mail server daemons might log to /var/log/mail/…, your apache2 web server has its own configurable logging locations, etc.

So, /var/log is usually a place you find relevant log files, but you'd want to look into the configuration of the services you run; at least, every service that gets started through the usual ways gets logged to journal and listed in `systemctl status`.

> For example dmesg provides logging of system before systemd is fully activated and presents a more precise view of hardware states and process.

don't mistake `dmesg` for a *competitor* to the journal: it is just the command that outputs your kernel's log buffer. It doesn't log anything but kernel messages. And as such, yes, it is in working state before journald can start logging. But, if you do `journalctl -b0` to read the log from the beginning of your current boot, you *should* see the same messages you see at the beginning of `dmesg`'s output. So, what you can see on a running system through `dmesg` should be a strict subset of what you can see via `journalctl`.